# cosmos setup fiware map reduce thrwing error

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, fiware-cosmos

I am working on cosmos setup on fiware lab and installed cosmos-tidoop, 
cosmos-gui, cosmos-auth .

I want to do map reduce work in cosmos tidoop for which I am following this 
guide as below:

https://fiware-cosmos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_and_programmer_manual/using_tidoop/index.html

But am not able to understand how can I use api to reduce some text file and 
get output for that.

I have started cosmos-tidoop on port 12000.

I am using commands on cli using : curl POST –X 
http://localhost:12000/opt/hadoop/my_storage/abc.txt

Which throws error:

curl POST http://localhost:12000/opt/hadoop/my_storage/README.txt

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Unknown error

{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}

How can perform map reduce on any file?